# Why does only one of the two objects from array get passed as prop?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-props

[image]Im trying to pass a prop to another component. The data(event) is coming from a fetch call. I do get the props but not in the way i was expecting.
When i console.log in willMount i only was able to get the first object and when i console log in the render funtion i did receive both objects. I would ideally like to get both object in the willMount function. Can any one explain why this happens and if their is a way to have them both console log in willMount? Tha[image: how whoHasGame is called]nk you.[image: the console logs]

```js
//PARENT
whoHasGame = (event) => {
        if(event.error){
            return;
        }else{
            console.log("event in MV", event)//console logs correctly
            this.setState({
                leagueInfo: <LeagueCard event={event}/>
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.state.leagueInfo}
            </ScrollView>    
            );
    }

  //CHILD
  export default class LeagueCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }


  componentWillMount() { 
    console.log(this.props.event) //only the first object makes it
  };



  render() {
    //console.log(this.props.event)<-- but here both objects make it

    return (
      <View>
        <CardSection>
          <Text>League Name Goes Here</Text>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.display}>
          <Card>
            <CardSection>
              {this.state.matches}
            </CardSection>
          </Card>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it `componentWillMount ` or `componentDidMount` ?  In que . u said `didMount`.Also please share how `whoHasGame ` is getting call with dom

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN its will mount my apologizes. and i also screen shot how whoHasGame is called.

Comment: both object are not getting console in  one render.They are rendering one by one from your shared outut.Please correct me.`componentWillMount ` called only once in lifecycle.`render` is called for each update

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN that is correct. And that seems like that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per current implementation :

```
this.setState({
                leagueInfo: <LeagueCard event={event}/>
            })
```

First time when `whoHasGame` is called,`setState` is called. it mount the component `LeagueCard`  with first object.

As  `componentWillMount` is called only once in life cycle, it will print that object.It also console it in `render`.

Now, again when `whoHasGame` is called,it get re-render  with second object because of `setState` is called

This time,`componentWillMount` is not getting called but `render` again get called and console the second object.

It will continue till nth object.

To get  all object during first time when  component rendered, you need to call `setState` once.

In your case `setState` is called `nth` time based on object count